# Configure multiple repos in Elixir app

Tags: elixir, erlang-supervisor, ecto

I am trying to configure two repos in my Elixir app using [Ecto](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/0.4.0/Ecto.html).
I need help to configure them so they are both supervised independently with a one_for_one strategy; I assume this is correct and will mean processes using them will restart

Repo-A and Repo-B

**mix.exs setup**:

```
def application do
  [applications: [:logger, :tds, :tds_ecto, :ecto, :httpoison, :csvlixir],
   mod: {MyApp, []}]
end
```

**MyApp_app.ex**

Snippet below:

```
def start(_type, _args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec, warn: false

   children = [
   supervisor(MyApp.Repo-A, []), 
   worker(Task, [MyAppModule, :work, []], restart: :temporary),
   supervisor(MyApp.Repo-B, []), 
   worker(Task, [MyAppModule, :work, []], restart: :temporary)
 ]

 # See http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Supervisor.html
 # for other strategies and supported options
 opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: MyApp.Supervisor]
 Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
end

defmodule Repo-A do
  use Ecto.Repo, otp_app: :myapp
end

defmodule Repo-B do
  use Ecto.Repo, otp_app: :myapp
end
```

When I `mix run` I get the following - I am not sure how to define the **id** correctly.

```
** (Mix) Could not start application myapp: exited in: MyApp.start(:normal, [])
 ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
     ** (ArgumentError) duplicated id Task found in the supervisor  specification, please explicitly pass the :id option when defining this worker/supervisor
```

Comment: I don't think the issue is related to Ecto, isn't it a result of calling  `worker(Task, [MyAppModule, :work, []], restart: :temporary),` twice?

Comment: @Gazler - yes, agreed not an issue with Ecto - just my noob usage of it :) I'm not sure how to configure the supervisor and worker for two repos - I'm sure my posted code is wrong...

Answer (score 4):

You add the `id` arg to the `opts` keyword list, for instance:

```
worker(Task, [MyAppModule, :work, []], restart: :temporary, id: :my_app_module_1)
```

Comment: Jason - thanks for the input, tho I'm not marking this as the correct answer because although it does let us define the Id it does not permit the two Recto modules to be registered independently; the second repo is not available for use. Apologies if the question is unclear but the question does start with the problem of config two repos.

Comment: I apparently am not fully following your full problem then.  Sorry.  The error output you provided seemed to point to the `id` being the problem.